# nodejs: binding error in query with like

Tags: mysql, node.js

in using nodejs and have and api that recieve a criteria, but when im binding the criteria in a query is not working, the query is this

```
SELECT id_comercio, nombre, nit, email FROM coma_comercios WHERE nombre LIKE "%?%"
```

but the database is reciving in this way

```
  SELECT id_comercio, nombre, nit, email FROM coma_comercios WHERE nombre LIKE "%\'buff\'%"
```

the binding is buff but instead of sendin LIKE "%buff%", its sending LIKE "%\'buff\'%"

i need a way to binding correctly the ?

can someone help me?

this is mi model thas use the query

```
ComComercios.prototype.comerciosCriterio = function(criterio) {
var d = q.defer();
this.crud.query(Queries.select_com_comercios_where_criterio, [criterio])
.then((comercios) => {
    if(comercios[0] != null ){
        console.log(comercios);
        d.resolve(comercios[0]);
    }
    else {
        console.log(comercios);
        d.reject(Messages.comercios.comercios_not_found);
    }
})
.fail((err) => {
    console.log(err);
    d.reject(Messages.db.db_error);
});
return d.promise;
};
```

im using node 9.4.0  and express 4.0.39

Comment: Please add your actual NodeJS code.

Comment: Try to move the `%` outside of the query string.

Comment: @GabrielBleu i already try that and dosn´t work :/

Comment: You could make the % part of `criterio` itself instead of the query. Query would have just ?. If you have tried this, what was the output in this case?

Comment: honestly i have try this to and doesn't work but now a try again and works, the solution was  criterio = "%"+criterio+"%"; before sending and the query SELECT id_comercio, nombre, nit, email FROM com_comercios WHERE nombre LIKE ?, thanks a lot @Vasan

Comment: im kinda new here, i post the answer or @Vasan post the answer and a check?

Comment: I suppose since @GabrielBleu suggested it first, they're the right one to post the answer. I just added more details.

Comment: @vasan go ahead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind variables cannot be used for partial string replacement, they are only used as a whole string.

So use bind variable for the entire LIKE expression.

Instead of `nombre LIKE "%?%"` do `nombre LIKE ?`

Then your `criterio` will need to be surrounded with wildcard character '%'

i.e. `'%' + criterio + '%'` or `['%',criterio,'%'].join('')`